# WebView embed youtube video position

Tags: swift, webview

[image: EXAMPLE HERE!!!]

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            secondVideoPlayer.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
            secondVideoPlayer.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(newVideoPlayer.frame.width)\" height=\"\(newVideoPlayer.frame.height)\" src=\"\(urlString)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",baseURL: nil)
    }
```

Youtube video position starts not correctly, to see it correctly i always have to drag it how can i fix it? How can i manually set his start position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `iframe` inside a `body` and set the `margin` and `padding` to zero, so the content begins from the top left.

```
secondVideoPlayer.loadHTMLString("<body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0;\"><iframe width=\"\(newVideoPlayer.frame.width)\" height=\"\(newVideoPlayer.frame.height)\" src=\"\(urlString)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body>",baseURL: nil)
secondVideoPlayer.scrollView.bounces = false
```

Comment: Thank you very much one more how can i make it not draggable?

Comment: if you want to disable the bounce effect, then write `secondVideoPlayer.scrollView.bounces = false`